# Bitbucket repository not build failed in Jenkins

Tags: php, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I created a project in jenkins and added the repository url, saved and tried to build and got the following error:

```
Started by user Ayotunde Salako
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url         https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from     https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git fetch --tags --progress     https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git      +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from     https://user@bitbucket.org/companyhttps://user@bitbucket.org/company/repo.gitids/repo.git
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1051)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1082)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
at     jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at     hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:401)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags     --progress https://user@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a     third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in     your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for     'https://user@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git/'

at     org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImp    l.java:1752)
at     org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials    (CliGitAPIImpl.java:1495)
at     org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.jav    a:64)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:795)
... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please what am I doing wrong? Jenkins was installed on a CentOs server.

Comment: In what way is this question related to PHP? Btw.. isn't the error message: _"Authentication failed for     'https://user@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git/'"_ kind of self explanatory?

Comment: I hid the user, company and repository. I entered the right credentials and still get the error. This is the url I entered in the Source Code Management section of Jenkins for the job: https://user:password@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git Build has been failing just because the repository could not be cloned by Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Bitbucket to host our Git repositories.

I've configured all my Jenkins jobs with ssh URLs (and not http + user/password).
All my slaves are using the same ssh key and I've declared this key on all my Bitbucket projects.

A [useful link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html) to set-up SSH for Bitbucket cloud.

I would recommend to use this method to clone your repositories with Jenkins.

If you prefer using a HTTPS URL, here is a [solution](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html):

I hope it will help :)